# How can I make two core share their processors?

Tags: ubuntu, caching, cpu, intel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6oU8.png)

This is my information when I saw my cache in Ubuntu 16.04
How can I make the core 0 share with core 4 in order that I can create a cache covert channel between them?
My cpuinfo is: i5-8250U 4 core - 8 threads

Comment: If they have the same `core id` in `/proc/cpuinfo`, they already do share a physical core.  Otherwise they don't, and maybe core 0 and 1 are HT siblings.   You can't easily change how the kernel enumerates logical cores of your physical core.   So find which logical cores share a physical core, and pin your  threads to them with `taskset`.

Comment: My processor 0 and 4 are the same core id, but when I check the share_cpu of processor 0 I didn't see 4 in the list. Does it affect the sharing?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  `/proc/cpuinfo` on my system (kernel version 5.16) doesn't have a `share_cpu` field, and you left the details out of your question so IDK what you're referring to.  But software can't change the physical layout of your CPU.

Comment: Don't post output console as pic, please